# how to use regex in ejs (browser build)?

Tags: javascript, browser, ejs

> i'm using ejs in the browser,

so I was trying to use regex to add a thousand separator, it works fine in vanilla js but it doesn't seem to work in ejs.

```
<%= product.price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/,","); %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question. However, for those stumbling accross it, the solution is to use the unescaped embedding operator `<%-` for ejs instead of the escaped operator (`<%=`):

```
<%- product.price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/,","); %>
```

The above will execute the code in the embed and display the result.